# antd table adding a new row with input

Tags: reactjs, antd

there.
I am recently using antd table, but I got a problem.

Here is the story:

1. I want to add a new row with input on the table, so I can type and save.
2. It works well, but when there are many previous table data, the performance is pretty slow whenever I type something on the new row I just added.
3. I searched on google and they introduced a method which was

```
shouldCellUpdate={(record, prevRecord) => !_.isEqual(record, prevRecord)}
```

4. The performance became fast, but when I try to modify the previous table data on the table, the new row I added disappeared.

Is there any solution to keep the performance fast and not disappearing the new row?